# Why does Outlook repeatedly requests user passwords?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, passwords, user-accounts

Since a recent Windows 10 update I have had several issues with applications not working. Most I have resolved but the one that is casing most concern is Outlook. It refused to run and after may attempts to resolve, I was forced to create a new profile.

Now , every time it synchronizes with my yahoo accounts (I have 3) it requests the password, despite the "save password to password list" box  being ticked.

I have tried removing the accounts and creating new accounts but this doesn't help and the "test account settings" step always fails on the first attempt on the password being rejected, but is successful the second time even if nothing is changed. I have uninstalled Outlook and re-installed with no change. I have tried alternative mail clients (eM client, Claws mail and opera mail, and they have no problems with my accounts or passwords.

I would like to know if it's possible for Outlook to be saving two versions of the passwords for each accounts (one correct one wrong), using a different password at different occasions. If this is possible how can I delete all account information and start again (by registry editing maybe)?

Comment: Understanding you are a new user, I want to give you a couple tips for posting questions. Please format the body of your question so it is readable. A huge block of text will often be dismissed because it is hard on the eyes. Secondly, please give details of what you are working with. In this case, we know you are using Windows 10, but no idea what version of Outlook. Considering the issue you are asking about is Outlook, the version is important. There is more info in *[ask]*.